# Install HPLIP-3.17.10 after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: software-installation, printing, 17.10, hplip

After I upgraded from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 I've found it's not possible to install HPLIP-3.17.10

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to install hplip:

- Download a standalone file like `hplip-3.17.10.run` and run it in the shell. This method doesn't work for me any more after upgrading to 17.10, so I used the other method which works fine for me
- Use the trivial solution `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui`. This worked fine for me in Artful.

Comment: Installing the version from the official repositories is always the preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

How I checked if the HPLIP was installed in my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Debian package based distributions (Debian, Ubuntu, Mepis, etc):

Run in a terminal window:

dpkg -l hplip

Will output something like this:

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Installed/Config-files/Unpacked/Failed-config/Half-installed
|/ Err?=(none)/Hold/Reinst-required/X=both-problems (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)

### ||/ Name             Version                  Description

ii  hplip            1.7.3-0ubuntu1           HP Linux Printing and Imaging

If you see "ii" in the first column before "hplip", then HPLIP is already installed.

Answer (score -1):

HPLIP should be installed by default. You can try `hp-setup -i` paste in terminal.

Comment: which HP printer are you using please?

Answer (score -1):

I got this issue solved for me. 
i'm not sure if it will do anything for your problem, but it fixed mine.

1) installed fresh install from ubuntu 17.10:

```
# sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

and later on for different reasons a complete new one from usb drive.

2) made sure all references (so far i knew to find them) from /etc/cups basically sudo-ed and cleaned the entire folder out.

3) auto-removed hplip-gui

```
# sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove hplip-gui
```

4) auto-removed hplip

```
# sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove hplip
```

5) downloaded hplip-3.17.11 from hp site

6) installed hplip-3.17.11 following the installation notes from hp side

8) payed special attention to the installation notes at the beginning of the install.. and did them as such.

8a) software and updates: made sure it was on main-server
  8b) locked the cd-rom by:

```
# eject -i 1
```

9) installed hplip-3.17.11

```
# cd desktop
# sh hplip-3.17.11.run
```

no dependency problems at all!

10) this hplip already has a gui build in and at the end of the run it will install your printer directly. so be sure what you say yes or no too!

so printer seems to be properly set-up,
no communication error 5012,
via wifi,
just still not found by xsane.

update:

i do get a different a HPLIP error: Unable to communicate with device (code=12), still it seems to work for me.

and oh, i'm a rather newby, this is how it worked for me, without a problem, but i can't garantee it will do the same for you, or help out if problems arrise (willing, but maybe not able) just warning!

the install went really smooth for me though.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/813666)

Comment: i will do just that, in a few days.. bit short in time and struggling to solve some issues myself. but comment is taken in account and i will do just that.

Comment: as promised i edited the complete howto in here (did filter the part out where i got to update to 18.04, since i re=installed 17.10 afterwards and did the same thing again.

Comment: why downvote / delete vote without comment? if i did something wrong, please explain.